# Only unsaved queries allow me to change the file name when I save with Ctrl-S

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I cannot see any Save-As functionality for previously-saved queries.

For example, if I type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> to create a new query, then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> to save it, a dialog box opens prompting for a new file name (or I can accept the default name, which looks something like *SQLQuery45.sql*).

But once I have saved a query there's no easy way (short of pasting it into a new query window) to save it with a different name or in a different folder.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server Management Studio v18.2 (15.0.18142.0) you can use "**Save *xxx.sql* As...**" command under "File":

[image]

I tried it on a query already saved to a file (SQLQuery5.sql) and everything works fine (unfortunately there is no keyboard shortcut).